# ARKit Entity and Model

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I add this figure to my box.

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
var cards: [Entity] = []

cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "toy_drummer") 

    .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "toy_robot_vintage"
    .collect()

    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (error) in

    cancellable?.cancel()

    }, receiveValue: { entities in

        var objects: [ModelEntity] = []

        for entity in entities {

            entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

            //here I append to my objects all the entities with a for loop
```

After this I iterate my index and objects like this

```
for (index, object) in objects.enumerated() {
     cards[index].addChild(object)
}
cancellable?.cancel()
```

My question is:

Let's say I have more than 2 model (toy_drummer, toy_robot_vintage etc ...) I need to perform some operation based on those model name values.

I add a ***tap gesture recognizer*** to my arView and every time I tap on something I would like to know the name in order to perform other operations. But I can't really understand how to do it.

My final purpose is to compare if the first box tapped is equal to the second one, so if I know the model value I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this one:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
    
    if let hitResult = arView?.entity(at: tapLocation) {
         print(hitResult.name)
    }
}
```

Or using hitTest:

```
let hitResult = scnView?.hitTest(tapLocation).first
```